# MX records problem

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I'm trying to set up MX records so they point to an external mail server. My zone file looks like this:

```
@                        IN A       x.x.x.x
localhost                IN A       127.0.0.1
mail                     IN A       x.x.x.x
www                      IN A       x.x.x.x
imap                     IN CNAME   www
loopback                 IN CNAME   localhost
pop                      IN CNAME   www
smtp                     IN CNAME   mail
@                        IN MX 10   mx.externalmailhost.com
@                        IN MX 20   mx2.externalmailhost.com
```

x.x.x.x is the IP for my domain.

Both nslookup and the external mail host tell me that they're seeing mx.externalmailhost.com.mydomain.com, i.e. my domain is simply added to the MX domain. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put periods on the ends of the MX records.

(Forceds them to be FQDN instead of relative).